# Extend CentOS LVM

Tags: linux, centos, lvm

I have a VM running CentOS 7.
It used a 1TB virtual disk to store data. Now i want to extend this 1TB disk to 1.5TB.
I've added extra 500GB through the hypervisor but i'm stuck now in adding these extra 500GB to the LVm group.

Could you help me with that?

```
# lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
vda             252:0    0  100G  0 disk
├─vda1          252:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─vda2          252:2    0   99G  0 part
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0   50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─centos-swap 253:1    0  7,9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─centos-home 253:2    0    1T  0 lvm  /home
vdb             252:16   0  1,5T  0 disk
└─vdb1          252:17   0  1,5T  0 part
  └─centos-home 253:2    0    1T  0 lvm  /home
```

```
# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/vdb: 1649.3 GB, 1649267441664 bytes, 3221225472 sectors
Units = Sektoren of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00009a2a

   Gerät  boot.     Anfang        Ende     Blöcke   Id  System
/dev/vdb1            2048  3221225471  1610611712   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units = Sektoren of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 8455 MB, 8455716864 bytes, 16515072 sectors
Units = Sektoren of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-home: 1143.7 GB, 1143656677376 bytes, 2233704448 sectors
Units = Sektoren of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

as you can see "vdb1" is already 1.5TB but not the centos-home partition.

Comment: The safest way would be to create a new partition on /dev/vdb (type lvm) and then run `vgextend centos /dev/vdb2` if the new partition would be vdb2. You could also simply run `pvextend /dev/vdb1` and then `vgextend ...` and then `lvresize ...` if necessary.

Comment: @eblock the partition has already been extended, so creating a new partition isn’t an option. `pvresize` will resize the PV, no need to change the VG, and then `lvextend` can be used to extend the LV and its file system.

Comment: @StephenKitt thank you very much, that worked for me! :)

Comment: @StephenKitt you're right of course, I should read the details more carefully, thanks for pointing that out and providing the solution.